# Which SQL Server Agent job is processing my tabular model database

Tags: sql-server-agent, tabular-model

I have a server called SANDBOX with two SQL 2014 instances SANDBOX\00 and SANDBOX\01. It also has a tabular model instance SANDBOX\TABULAR. Agent jobs are disabled on SANDBOX\01. There is no agent (as far as I can see) on SANDBOX\TABULAR.

There is a tabular model database on SANDBOX\TABULAR that is being refreshed every two hours, but for the life of me, I can't locate the agent job that is running this process. I've checked, and as far as I can tell there is no agent job on the source or destination server that would be refreshing the model.

The source data is on a different server. I ran a profiler trace on that database to get that ApplicationName that was pulling the data, but it just returned NULL. It returns the HostName (SANDBOX) of the destination server (but without any instance details).

I ran a profiler trace on the destination database (the tabular model db) and it did show the refresh happening, but in ApplicationName it did not show the name of the agent job that was initiating it. This trace captured the ClientHostName (10.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX). Is this something I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. ClientHostName in the SSAS profiler trace should tell you which server is kicking off processing.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I've been away from work and the internet for the past few days. I'll give this some further investigation and post back.